# Why Netty become slow when data packet bigger than 8k

Tags: performance, netty

When using Netty, the received data package bigger than 8k, CPU occupation become high and slow, but small data package was Ok, can sb help this

I tried some config, but can’t solve it. Is sb meet the same problem? It seems weird, I don’t have big computation task.